# PJSIP integration in Docker: Call and request timeouts

Tags: python, docker, sip, pjsip

I'm trying to integrate PJSIP into a Docker container for my VoIP application. However, I'm encountering some issues with call and request timeouts when running the application inside the container. The same application runs without any problems on my local machine.

Here's an overview of the setup and the problems I'm facing:

- I'm using Docker to containerize my VoIP application, which utilizes the PJSIP library for SIP communication.
- I've created a Docker image based on python:3.9.16-slim-buster.
- The application starts up successfully within the container.
  However, when making a call or sending any other SIP request, I'm experiencing timeouts consistently.
- The same application, without Docker, runs without any issues on my local machine.

```
FROM python:3.9.16-slim-buster AS dependencies

ARG VERSION_PJSIP=2.13.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    make \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    swig \
    libssl-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libasound2-dev \
    libv4l-dev \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libx264-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavdevice-dev \
    libavfilter-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavresample-dev \
    libavutil-dev \
    libpostproc-dev \
    libswresample-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libopus-dev \
    libportaudio2 \
    --assume-yes \
    --no-install-recommends

FROM dependencies AS pjsip

WORKDIR /root

RUN wget https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/archive/refs/tags/$VERSION_PJSIP.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf $VERSION_PJSIP.tar.gz && \
    cd pjproject-$VERSION_PJSIP && \
    export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC" && \
    ./configure --enable-shared \
    --disable-video && \
    make dep all && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    make clean && \
    ldconfig

FROM pjsip AS python-pjsip

WORKDIR /root/pjproject-$VERSION_PJSIP/pjsip-apps/src/swig/python

RUN make && \
    make install
```

Comment: I guess the issue is in network configuration. Try to forward ip address and port using e.g. "expose".

Comment: I guess you are right, doing some shenanigans to run 10 scripts at a time seems to work nicely, I guess using docker is not a option for now or I'm just dumb to not know how to use it.